# Disable cleartype Windows 7 title bar text

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

Removed Segoe UI and its similar fonts.

Changed every font to Arial in Advanced appearance settings.

Regedit font substitutes Segoe UI to Dotum.

Windows 7 Help appear blurry text, so I removed Internet Explorer 11 for back to Internet Explorer 8. Now, Windows 7 Help display crisp font.

I went content option in Firefox make just use my Font, so website must display Arial for sans-serif, Times New Roman for serif, Courier New for monospace. No more web font.

So above methods make Windows 7 display crisp font like Windows XP except... title bar still appear cleartype. How can I disable cleartype on title bar text?